# meaning of "open to"

Tags: word-meaning

I am working on Gmat exam, and I am having problem understanding one of the answer choices.

> Passage: Many environmentalists hold that the natural environment is morally
>   valuable for its own sake, regardless of any benefits it provides us.
>   However, even if nature has no moral value, nature can be regarded as
>   worth preserving simply on the grounds that people find it beautiful.
>   Moreover, because it is philosophically disputable whether nature is
>   morally valuable but undeniable that it is beautiful, an argument for
>   preserving nature that emphasizes nature's beauty will be less
>   vulnerable to logical objections than one that emphasizes its moral
>   value.
>
> Q: The ethicist's reasoning most closely conforms to which one of the
>   following principles?
>
> (A) **An argument for preserving nature will be less open to logical
>   objections if it appeals to a characteristic that can be regarded as a
>   basic for preserving nature and that philosophically indisputably
>   belongs to nature.**
>
> (B)....................... (C)......................
>   (D).......................

I have two interpretations for bold sentence.

1. An argument is not accepting logical objections because the objections have characteristic of  ~~~~
2. An argument is less vulnerable to logical objections because the argument has the characteristic of ~~~~

Please explain which one is correct and why the other is incorrect. Thanks!

Comment: What I mean by "not accepting" is "not agreeing and welcoming". So my first interpretation is "argument does not agree and accept logical objections because the objections can be regarded as ~~~". So I guess this interpretation is wrong and the second one is correct, right?

Comment: First, let me apologise for the typos in my comment. Some letters failed to register. It should have read: *"Less open to, Not accepting of, and Less vulnerable to" are three different ways of saying almost the same thing. But they are nuanced differently. I would say that not accepting of is the odd one out, that is a little different to the other two*. Saying that "an argument is not accepting of something", is an unusual idiom. It comes across as erudite but unusual, a sort of metaphorical way of speaking. But it definitely needs an "of", following "accepting".